# Strange Unhandled Exception from mono

Tags: c#, linux, mono, monodevelop

We use mono 4.8.0 for our product. When running particular testings on different kinds of Linux, we got unhandled exception triggered occasionally. More specifically AppDomain.UnhandledException event triggered. But we can't figure out which line of our code triggered the exception. I'm wondering is this a defect of mono?

> [ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.ExecutionEngineException: ExecutionContext_ExceptionInAsyncLocalNotification ---> System.Threading.ThreadAbortException
>     at System.Collections.Generic.ObjectEqualityComparer'1[T].Equals (T x, T y) <0x7f0f20aa1e80 + 0x00000> in :0
>     at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary'2[TKey,TValue].FindEntry (TKey key) [0x0005d] in :0
>     at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary'2[TKey,TValue].TryGetValue (TKey key, TValue& value) [0x00000] in :0
>     at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.OnAsyncLocalContextChanged (System.Threading.ExecutionContext previous, System.Threading.ExecutionContext current) [0x00119] in ...../mono/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/executioncontext.cs:749
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>     at System.Environment.FailFast (System.String message, System.Exception exception) [0x00000] in ...../mono/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System/Environment.cs:929
>     at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.OnAsyncLocalContextChanged (System.Threading.ExecutionContext previous, System.Threading.ExecutionContext current) [0x00164] in ..../mono/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/executioncontext.cs:758
>     at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.SetExecutionContext (System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Boolean preserveSyncCtx) [0x0005f] in ..../mono/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/executioncontext.cs:1028

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try `<AppContextSwitchOverrides value="Switch.System.Globalization.NoAsyncCurrentCulture=true" />` and avoid using `AsyncLocal<T>`

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. This setting makes the exception occurring less. The stack was also a little different.

Comment: take a look at this code: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/executioncontext.cs,742

Comment: If this code is running under a dedicated thread, and when call thread abort, It would fail fast

Comment: didn't see any call of thread abort. Might be related to inappropriate using of remote service in the code. still digging it.